# Remove Action in libgdx

Tags: libgdx, action

I´m using Scene2D and I have a ball. this ball is an actor and it does an action when the ball hit the rectangle, and when the action finished the ball continue moving arround the screen.

But I want that when the ball hit the rectangle again it do the action again, but i don´t know how do it.

Code:`private void muerte() {

```
    if(choque){
        System.out.println("choque");

        velocidadbolax=0;
        velocidadbolay=0;

        //bola.addAction(a1);

        bola.addAction(Actions.sequence(a1, Actions.run(new Runnable() {
               public void run () {
                velocidadbolax=95;
                velocidadbolay=30;
            }
         })));





        }

        }
```

Choque is a boolean of the colision. When the colision happened the ball stoped, and the action start, then,when the action finished, the ball move.

Comment: Can you show where you define velocidadbolax velocidadbolay and y? I did not know you can set fields inside an anonymous class like that. Usually I would have to call a method of the class instead.

Comment: Sorry, and i have an error in the code that i copy. The y is a number, 30

Comment: Velocidadbolax and velocidadbolay are simple int

Answer (score 0):

You can  add action to actor in the same way as you do this when you detect first collision.

```
 actor.addAction(sequence(fadeIn(2), run(new Runnable() {
       public void run () {
        System.out.println("Action complete!");
    }
 })));
```

Thre you can find more info: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d

Comment: Yes, but whent i try this the first time the action go well, but then the program crash and it said that the problem is in the method act of the ball